# How to read a single column from a cursor defined with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a cursor:

```
DECLARE db_inner_cursor_info CURSOR FOR Select Col1 , Col2 ..... from TBL1

OPEN db_inner_cursor_info
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_inner_cursor_info
    INTO @Col1
    print @Col1
etc.
```

I only need values from `TBL1.Col1`, but I cannot remove the rest of the columns from the `SELECT` statement within the declaration of the cursor.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: **why** can't you remove the rest of the columns from the `SELECT`?

Comment: Then why you declare a cursor for selecting all those columns?

Comment: If you can't remove them from the select statement, then you'll have to declare variables for all columns and only use the ones you want.

Comment: The point is, why would you declare your `cursor` selecting all of those columns if you aren't going to use those columns in the `fetch`?

Comment: Because after col1 the rest of the columns are dynamic.

Comment: Do you use any of the other columns later in the stored procedure?

Comment: @DaniyalTariq What do you mean the columns are dynamic?

Comment: I m making select query dynamically that is why I need only first col.

Comment: No I don't use any other column in the procedure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really cannot alter the `SELECT` statement in the cursor declaration (which I would argue you absolutely should be able to), then your only option is the also fetch the other columns from that `SELECT` statement into variables within your `INTO` clause, even if you do not use these variables for anything:

```
DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Col2 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Col3 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Col4 VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE db_inner_cursor_info CURSOR FOR Select Col1 , Col2, Col3, Col4 from TBL1

OPEN db_inner_cursor_info
FETCH NEXT FROM db_inner_cursor_info INTO @Col1, @Col2, @Col3, @Col4

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @Col1
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_inner_cursor_info INTO @Col1, @Col2, @Col3, @Col4
END

CLOSE db_inner_cursor_info
DEALLOCATE db_inner_cursor_info
```

As you can see, while we fetch values from all of the columns in `TBL1`, we only use the value from `Col1`.

Comment: Correct, I cannot think of any situation (other than, perhaps, a more senior dev just saying so - but I would still question that) where you are prevented from altering your `declare` statement to match the requirements of the associated `fetch`. Why would you `declare` and `select` columns for a cursor that are never going to be used? That makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's confusing as why you need all columns in your `SELECT` but you can select into multiple variable like below. Define variables for the list of columns in your `SELECT` part

```
DECLARE db_inner_cursor_info CURSOR FOR Select Col1 , Col2, col3 from TBL1

OPEN db_inner_cursor_info
                FETCH NEXT FROM db_inner_cursor_info
                INTO @Col1, @Col2, @Col3
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a pretty strange requirement, but you can declare additional variables, fetch next into them additional variables but do nothing with them . Something like....

```
Declare @Col1 Varchar(10), @Col2 Varchar(10),..... 

DECLARE db_inner_cursor_info CURSOR FOR 
Select Col1 , Col2 ..... from TBL1

OPEN db_inner_cursor_info

FETCH NEXT FROM db_inner_cursor_info INTO @Col1, @Col2 .......
```